# Adding module to python at runtime

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I have a python script that does this at the begining of the script:

```
def initialize(module_name):
    return importlib.import_module(module_name) # import module from string
```

I want to write a test that 'mocks' out the module name like so:

```
def test():
    # assemble module at run time
    module_obj = {'name': Object, 'another_name': AnotherObject}

    # inject to the "import system"
    inject_mock_module('mymodule', module_obj)

    # assert that the import went correctly
    assert my_module_mock == initialize('mymodule')
```

How do I do this? First, specifically, how to I create `module_obj` and how do I define `inject_mock_module`? This needs to work in both 2.7+ and 3.3+

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`mock` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) to mock out the `import_module()` function. As of Python 3.3, you can import that module as [`unittest.mock`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html):

```
try:
    # Python 3.3+
    from unittest.mock import patch
except ImportError:
    # External dependency
    from mock import patch

def test():
    module_obj = {'name': Object, 'another_name': AnotherObject}

    with patch('importlib.import_module', new=module_obj.get):
        assert initialize('name') is module_obj['name']
```

Comment: Readers, please note that the second argument to patch() used here is "new", not the more usual "return_value".

Comment: @Manur: `return_value` is not a positional argument in `mock.patch()`. I've made it more explicit by using `new` as a keyword argument now, but it would be impossible to pass in `return_value` as a positional argument *anyway*.